# Business Catalyst Web Apps cannot use jQuery on the Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, business-catalyst

I created a Web App for NavBar and located it on my template. It is working fine.

```
{module_webapps,28592,a,,,,false,20,false,1}
```

And this is the code for this WebApp:

```
<li>
   <a id="{tag_href-id}" href="{tag_href-id}">{tag_title}</a>
</li>
```

Then, for showing the active page as highlighted, I coded this jQuery in my template:

```
window.onload = function(){
        var url = window.location.pathname;
        var index = url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1;
        var filenameWithExtension = url.substr(index);
        var filename = "#" + filenameWithExtension.split(".")[0];
        $(filename).addClass('active');

    };
```

The idea is adding `class="active"` inside of `a` tag; if its id equal to last part of the URL.

I used the same idea before, without WebApps. I wonder that, is there any limitation about using jQuery in a page, to change something about an element which comes from Web Apps? Could it be related page`s loading order. Or am I missing another thing?

Comment: What does the rendered page source look like? What does a sample URL look like? BC's responsibility ends as soon as the page source is rendered; if the rendered source is correct then the problem is either the browser or the javascript.

Comment: Since you have jquery loaded, it better to use .ready() to make sure the code loads when the DOM is ready.
http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/